# Seeking bathymetry for UK location?

Tags: data, united-kingdom, bathymetry

I'm wondering whether I can get water depth for the mudflats at Lindisfarne, NE England, UK: http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&hq=&ll=55.65,-1.821&z=13

The mudflats are intertidal, so I'm hoping to get water depth according to state of tide at any particular location on the mudflats.

Comment: Try the Channel Coast Observatory website http://www.channelcoast.org/

Comment: I think questions such as this may be better researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure these guys can help you out they have a full UK Bathymetric data set.
http://marinefind.co.uk/

Comment: specifically they offer free WMSses at http://marinefind.co.uk/resources/marine-wms , but don't directly provide URLs.